# Filter List of parent objects where List of child objects does not meet criteria

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Let's say we have two classes (parent and child):

```cs
class Task
{
    public int IdTask 
    public string Task
    public List<User> ListUser 
    public bool Deleted
}

class User
{
    public int IdUser 
    public string Task
}
```

and then a big list of tasks `List<Task>`.

Now, I would like to find a filtered list of `List<Task>` where none of the users in `ListUser` have a certain `IdUser` (for example 99).

Currently I do it with a nested loop. Smth like this:

```cs
foreach (var item in tasks)
{
    var access = false;
    foreach (var t in item.ListUser)
    {
        if(t.IdUser == 99)
        {
            access = true;
        }
    }
    item.Deleted = access;
}
tasks.RemoveAll(x => x.Deleted);
```

Although the above works, it seems like an overkill. Can I acomplish the same, with a lambda expression (or linq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var newList = list.Where(e => !e.ListUser.Any(l => l.IdUser == 99));
```

which says, in effect, "create a new list with all the items except those that have a user list containing user 99".

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
IEnumerable<Task> result=tasks.Where(task=> task.ListUser.Any(user=>user.IdUser == XXX))
```